# Spree: Create new asset failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, ruby-2.1

I am trying to create a custom form for a third role in Spree 2.3 (Designer). The designer creates a new product and variant, then uploads an image for that variant. My efforts have so far been in vain.

How can I create a new asset for a variant?

**Error**

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in Designers::SpreeAssetsController#create
unknown attribute: attachment
Extracted source (around line #11):
def create      
  @asset = Spree::Asset.new(asset_params) #line 11
  ...
end
```

**Request** parameters

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"XXX=",
"asset"=>{"attachment"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000010f6c34b8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/xk/r14w_thd2bn8vxch294zzn040000gn/T/RackMultipart20140731-5542-fgfzhn>,
@original_filename="DSCN0220.JPG",
@content_type="image/jpeg",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"asset[attachment]\"; filename=\"DSCN0220.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">},
"commit"=>"Create"}
```

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/designers/spree_assets_controller.rb
def create      
  @asset = Spree::Asset.new(asset_params)
...
end

private

def asset_params
  params.require(:asset).permit(:attachment)
end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for @asset, url: designers_spree_assets_path, method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :attachment, "Upload image" %></br>
  <%= f.file_field :attachment %></br>
  <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: so you're trying to target :attachment in the Image class?

Comment: In the asset class, yes. Or that's how the db tables read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the following association in the model, that has images:

```
has_many :images, :as => :viewable, :order => :position, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "Spree::Image"
```

This is how the Variant model has :images, do `bundle open spree` for more info.

Then create a nested form to create new attachment, I prefer simple_form

```
= simple_form_for @asset, :html => {:multipart => true } do |m|
  = m.simple_fields_for :images do |p|
    = p.file_field :attachment
```

Or a simpler way of doing it would be to include paperclips `has_attached_file` method in your model.

The following is from the Image model, just to give you an idea how product images are processed in Spree.

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
                  :styles => { :mini => '48x48>', :small => '100x100>', :product => '240x240>', :large => '600x600>' },
                  :default_style => :product,
                  :url => '/spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension',
                  :path => ':rails_root/public/spree/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension',
                  :convert_options => { :all => '-strip -auto-orient' }
```

Customize as needed.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It looks like that association is already setup in Spree. Should I rewrite it in a decorator? Otherwise, I'm not sure about your code. It looks like this means Asset has_many Images? I've tried to use this technique for 'form_for @variant... fields_for :images' with the same error message resulting.

Comment: decorator for which model? you don't have to add anything to existing models on spree, so no need to use decorator here, what's the error message you're getting?

Comment: Same: unknown attribute attacchment

Comment: And the decorator I was referring to was in regards to your association setup suggestion. That should be the Variant model, as best I can tell.

Comment: what would you like to add to the Variant model? I'm not able to see your setup so its a little hard to understand

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not being clear. Ultimately I just want to upload a new image. So far I'm unsure of everything else, as nothing is working. That may not add anything to the Variant model, but I thought your first line was suggesting that.

Comment: well I initially thought I needed to add a belongs_to on Image model through decorator, but :as => :viewable takes care of that, it should work as is, if its too hard just put has_attached_file on your current model instead of reusing the built in Image class

Comment: your last suggestion of adding has_attached_file (with content validation) in asset_decorator.rb was the answer. Thank you! If you want to update or change your answer to that solution, I'd be happy to upvote you.

Comment: done! feel free to edit as needed, would be awesome if you can accept answer/upvote.